# How to redirect from a PATCH route to a POST route?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, redirect, backend

In the controller of the PATCH route, there may be a redirection needed via:

```
res.redirect("/path")
```

However, "/path" is meant to be a POST route.

As it is, it is not working. Is the above possible? If so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible.

HTTP has a number of [redirection status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#redirection_messages) but they are all either:

- shouldn't but may convert to GET (301/302)
- MUST convert to GET (303)
- MUST preserve the same HTTP verb (307/308)

There aren't any which convert to POST.

Answer (score 2):

What @Quentin says is absolutely correct, but in the spirit of trying to help you solve your problem, what you CAN do is have the PATCH return an error. Then in the javascript response handler, you can look for that error and initiate the correct POST with the same form data that was provided in the original PATCH. So you still have to do two requests, but to the end user it should feel seamless.

Comment: Caveat: For a value of "you" equal to "every developer writing code to access your web service".